# not understanding a step in a proof

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Hi: I'm reading some introductory notes on hilbert spaces and there is a step in a proof that I don't follow. I will put the exact statement below. If someone could explain how it is obtained, it's appreciated. Note that commans between two terms when they have < and > around them denotes the innner product. Also, $e_{n}$ for $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$ is a complete orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ and $x$ is in $H$.

Proof: Observe that

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 <=  || x - \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x,e_{n}>e_{n}) ||^2 
& = & \left< x - \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x,e_{n}>e_{n}, x - \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x,e_{n}>e_{n} \right> \\
& = & \left< x, x - \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x,e_{n}>e_{n} \right> 
- \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x, e_{n}> \left < e_{n}, x - \sum_{n=1}^{m} <x,e_{n}>e_{n} \right > \\
& = & ||x||^2 - \sum_{n=1}^{m} |<x, e_{n}>|^2
\end{eqnarray*}

I understand the first two lines of above.
My question is how one goes from the second to the last line to the last line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the first inner product in the second-last line is:
$$ \left\langle x, x - \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\right\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle - \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle \langle x,e_n\rangle = \|x\|^2 - \sum_{n=1}^m |\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 $$
so we would hope that the second is equal to zero. We have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle\left\langle e_n, x - \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\right\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle\langle e_n,x\rangle - \sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle^2 \sum_{k=1}^m \langle e_n,e_k\rangle $$
Luckily, $\langle e_n,e_k\rangle = 1$ if $n=k$ and $0$ otherwise, so the two terms in the difference are equal.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity's sake, I've rewritten this second to last line as

$$\left< x, x - \sum_{n=1}^{m}\left[ <x,e_{n}>e_{n}\right] \right> 
- \sum_{n=1}^{m}\left[ <x, e_{n}> \left < e_{n}, x - \sum_{i=1}^{m} <x,e_{i}>e_{i} \right >\right].$$
By linearity of the inner-product,
$$\left< x, x - \sum_{n=1}^{m}\left[ <x,e_{n}>e_{n}\right] \right> =||x||^2-\sum_{n=1}^m \left[<x,e_n>^2\right].$$
Since $<e_n,e_m>=0$ whenever $m \neq n$ and $1$ otherwise, whenever $1 \leq n\leq m$, we find that
$$\left < e_{n}, x - \sum_{i=1}^{m} <x,e_{i}>e_{i} \right >=<e_n,x>-<x,e_n>=0,$$
since inner-products are symmetric. Hence the second term in the original expression is identically zero.
Hope that helps! Let me know if anything here is unclear.

Comment: I will print out, read carefully, make sure I understand it and then check it. Thank you very much for your thorough explanation. It's really appreciated.

Comment: both of you have answered so what am I supposed to do if I understand both explanations. which one do I check ? thanks.

Comment: @markleeds Don't mention it, glad to help. You can go ahead and give ptrsinclair the correct answer check, it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: I followed both of the explanations. Thanks again to both of you.